# Most elegant way of callback from method launched with async

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

What is the most elegant way to implement a non-static callback when starting a function with `async`?

Problem: I want a ui to show data after a computation finished without blocking the ui. Please don't consider using some ui event-loops that may be present in ui libraries because I'm looking for a more general and elegant solution using pure C++ (11).

I have a `MainWindow` class that handles the user interface and a `Simulation` class that makes some complex calculations in a non-static `run(SimulationSettings settings)` method. Part of the `settings` structure passed with the `run`-method is a pointer to a `DataManager`-object that stores input and output for the simulation. The `DataManager` as well as the `Simulation` are created as members of the `MainWindow`. I start the simulation with the following lines in a non-static method of the `MainWindow` class:

```
auto run_simulation = std::bind(&Simulation::run, m_simulation, settings);
std::async(run_simulation);
```

After the `run(...)` method returns I want my `MainWindow` to execute its method `processesResults()` that does some postprocessing with the data which is now saved in the `DataManager` - but of course without blocking the rest of the `MainWindow` functionality during the simulation. Is there a way to do this "callback" without giving the `Simulation` a pointer to the `MainWindow` object? Is it possible with a function pointer? Or is my whole concept of doing asynchronous work bad?
I'm pretty new to threads etc. and in my opinion it is a bit hard to find good writing about this C++11 area with the `thread`, `future`, `promise` ... classes.

Comment: Not exactly what you asking for, but you may adopt from http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47347/follow-up-timer-utilizing-stdfuture

Comment: @DieterLücking Thanks. I will have look into this. I definitely want to get a better understanding of these classes.

Comment: You may pass a `std::function`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Hm... but is it possible to create a function object from a member function of the `MainWindow` and then pass it to the `Simulation` without letting the latter anything know about the `MainWindow`-class? EDIT: Nevermind, it works using std::bind. Example: `std::function<void(double)> update = std::bind(&MainWindow::simulationProgress, this, std::placeholders::_1);` with the method `void simulationProgress(double progress)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to do something after the simulation finishes you can use the following lambda expression:

```
auto run_simulation = [this, &settings]() {
    m_simulation.run(settings);
    processResults();
};
std::async(run_simulation);
```

Comment: ...and don't forget to lock the caller with a `shared_ptr` for the duration of the call and use `mutex`es correctly to avoid data races in the callback. One of the problems of `async` is that you cannot guarantee which thread it will be run on. In the end you'll probably want control of that and find that something like the post mechanism of `asio::io_service` becomes necessary.

Comment: Well, the `processResults()` method belongs to the `MainWindow` class. Can I just adjust the lambda to replace the second call with `this->processResults()` or will this also freeze the `MainWindow`?

Comment: @RichardHodges What do you exactly mean with "lock the caller"? Actually I don't want to lock my `MainWindow`-object or which object do you refer to?

Comment: @w1th0utnam3 I don't know exactly what Richard means, but yes, you can adjust the lambda to replace the second call with a call to `this->whatever`, remember to add `this` to the lambda's capture clause. It will only freeze the `MainWindow` if you explicitly do so inside `processResults` or something. Also make sure `processResults` is thread-safe.

Comment: @let Thanks! It works. If you don't mind I will edit your answer to be correct for my case (lambdas cant capture members, it needs a pointer to the simulation + the usage of this) and accept it after you accepted the edit!

Comment: @w1th0utnam3 thanks, and I have made a change: if you capture `this`, the lambda can use the members of `this` without qualification.

Comment: What I mean by "locking the caller" is that you must guarantee that `this` is still valid when the callback occurs. The normal way to do this is to derive the class of `this` from `std::enable_shared_from_this<MyClass>` and then pass `this->shared_from_this()` into your callback. This way (assuming that `this` is held by a `shared_ptr`) you will not get a race on the destruction of your object at the time of the callback.

Comment: @RichardHodges I think that this cannot happen in my case but nevertheless a good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `future::wait_for` to know when the simulation finished

```
auto fut = std::async(run_similation);

while (true) {
    // Your main loop

    std::chrono::milliseconds span (1);
    if (fut.valid() && fut.wait_for(span) != std::future_status::timeout) {
        // simulation is finished
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would work but I was hoping for something with a direct callback.